# How can I find wrong character in Laravel from Webside?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very very very new to the topic of Laravel and I am currently doing a tutorial that recreates the Instagram platform. Unfortunately, I probably mistyped at some point and now the letter "n" is at the top left of the web page. (see picture) I have already tried to find the letter with Chrome Inspect but it is not in my code. Is there another way to find this error?

Thanks in advance
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally occurs when you have left a letter or character outside a chunk of code. For Example;

```
 n
 <div>
    {{ some blade code here }}
    <div>
         {{ even more blade code here }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the 'n' after the start of the div. Given the position of it in the screenshot you shared, I would start taking a look at your `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` ALternatively, if you use developer tools to `"inspect"` the erroneous `n` you might see in the overall html output where it is located

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have found the letter with Chrome inspect but it is not in my code. Since this letter is on every page, the error should be in app.blade.php as you said but the n is not there either.

Comment: I searched explicitly for the n and logically it was found quite often. But I was lucky and the third document was index.php in which the letter had crept in. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. I have had this kind of issue before... It can be a pain, but glad you found it! Good luck with your project :) and thanks for marking the answer - it helps.